# what is the meaning of => while using arrays in php

Tags: php

I have a php code.

```
$metadata = Array(
        'facebook'  => Array(
                'title'         => 'og:title',
                'type'          => 'og:type',
                'url'           => 'og:url',
                'thumbnail'     => 'og:image',
                'sitename'      => 'og:site_name',
                'key'           => 'fb:admins',
                'description'   => 'og:description'
            ),
        'google+'   => Array(
                'thumbnail'     => 'image',
                'title'         => 'name',
                'description'   => 'description'
            ),
        'twitter'   => Array(
                'card'          => 'twitter:card',
                'url'           => 'twitter:url',
                'title'         => 'twitter:title',
                'description'   => 'twitter:description',
                'thumbnail'     => 'twitter:image'
            )
    );
```

what does the => means. How to access an element in this array.

Comment: this is array .. $metadata['facebook']['type'] will give you 'og:type'

Comment: echo $metadata['facebook']['title'];

Comment: An array is a key/value store: when working with an array, the value ___before___ the `=>` is the `key`; the value ___after___ the `=>` is the `value`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Actually, none of the questions linked from that reference (including that explicitly linked by @DaveChen) ask about the use of `=>` during array declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multi dimensional array, so **facebook**, **google** and **twitter** are elements of the 1st dimension of the $metadata array and they are arrays themselves, here lies the multi dimension.

The **=>** is just like an arrow pointing to the value/data.

To access the 1st dimension would be **$metadata['twitter'];** or **$metadata[2];** it's the same statement, this would bring back the elements/keys of the twitter array.

To access the 2nd dimension would be 
**$metadata['twitter']['card'];** or **$metadata[2][0];** again the two statements are the same, this would bring back the value of the element/key **card**

Answer (score 0):

1. > what does the => means.

   As documented under [Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

   > An [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates *values* to *keys*.
   >
   > ```
   > [ deletia ]
   > ```
   >
   > An [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) can be created using the [array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated *key* => *value* pairs as arguments.
   >
   > ```
   > array(
   >     key  => value,
   >     key2 => value2,
   >     key3 => value3,
   >     ...
   > )
   > ```
2. > How to access an element in this array.

   As documented under [Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing):

   > Array elements can be accessed using the *array[key]* syntax.
   >
   > #### Example #6 Accessing array elements
   >
   > ```
   > <?php
   > $array = array(
   >     "foo" => "bar",
   >     42    => 24,
   >     "multi" => array(
   >          "dimensional" => array(
   >              "array" => "foo"
   >          )
   >     )
   > );
   >
   > var_dump($array["foo"]);
   > var_dump($array[42]);
   > var_dump($array["multi"]["dimensional"]["array"]);
   > ?>
   > ```
   >
   > The above example will output:
   >
   > ```
   > string(3) "bar"
   > int(24)
   > string(3) "foo"
   > ```